# removing a dynamic html in a if condition

Tags: javascript, html

i have a problem in a dynamic html block that i use for showing an error in an if condition.

in constructor:

```
constructor() {

this.body = $(".contact-block-header");
this.ErrorMasage = this.body.find(".error-masage");
this.events();
}
```

and here are the codes:

```
  if (addressData != '') {
    newContactObject = {
        'value': {
        "address" : addressData,
      },
      'type': 'address'
      };
  } else {
    this.ErrorMasage.fadeOut(1000);
    this.ErrorMasage.html('Please add a valid address..');
    this.ErrorMasage.fadeIn(1000);
    return 0;
  }
```

in these codes i said if the address data is empty, an error appears. The problem is when in the first time, i leave address input empty, the error comes up, as i want, but when i add information in the address input and save it, the error box is still there, i could not find a way to remove it after adding data in the address input. 
I will be appreciated if anyone helps me on that.

Comment: Needs more data. When is the if/else block executed? You need to ensure that the if/else block is executed again after you enter data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I am understanding your goal correctly in that you want the error message to be removed whenever a user submits non-empty input to an address field, one way could be to call `this.ErrorMasage.fadeOut(1000);` whenever the containing form is submitted (or if there is no form, whenever something is typed).

Assuming there is a form, you could do:

```
xxx.on('submit', (e) => {
  // ...other stuff

  this.ErrorMasage.fadeOut(1000);

  if (addressData != '') {
    newContactObject = {
      'value': {
      "address" : addressData,
    },
    'type': 'address'
    };
  } else {
    this.ErrorMasage.html('Please add a valid address..');
    this.ErrorMasage.fadeIn(1000);
    return 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is exactly that i wanted